# when i want to put a small image to the right of a text, it doesn't work

Tags: android, image, button, alignment

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/summary"
    android:text="Summary   "
    android:textSize="25px"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/summary_btn"
    android:src="@drawable/next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/summary"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/summary"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/summary"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
<FrameLayout>
```

I don't want to make this image a button .
But i don't see the error.

Comment: How doesn't it work? Does the image appear at all, or just nothing?

Comment: Yes but it's on the text, litteraly .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what's special about the id "summary", but if you change your ids so that the `TextView` is, say, `"@+id/s"` and the `ImageView` is, say, `"@+id/s_btn"` (and change the references in the `ImageView` to `"@id/s"` of course) then it seems to work.

Comment: You're right, it seems to work but why ? this is just an id right ?

Comment: Maybe "summary" is reserved for something? (*Waves hands vaguely*)

Comment: hmmmmmm yeah it must be it haha

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an `ImageView`, use the `TextView`'s [`android:drawableRight`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawableRight) attribute.

Comment: hmmm , there is the same mistake, i was thinking it was the relative layout the problem.

Comment: Did you remove your ImageView as well? What exactly is the problem anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Or use alignParentEnd="true" which is more accurate and for the job. this will move the image all the way to the end of wherever its sitting in (the relativeLayout parent).

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <com.cura.classes.TypefacedEditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordprompt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/showpassword_eye" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Result:

[image: TextView with drawable to its right]

And if you want the textField to stop at where the image begins, set its marginRight attr to the width of the image